# Answering a closed question with a time limit on a smartphone?

Tags: mobile-web, question-answer

For an app that displays a closed question on a smartphone and lets the user pick her answer within a time limit what would be more enjoyable for the user?

Q1. The user can keep changing her mind until the time is up?

VS. The user picks an answer and is kindly asked to wait until the quiz ends.

Q2. Have two different pages - one for before you pick an answer and one for after?

vs.  or would it be enough to keep the same page and just add *you picked answer x"

3.With the smartphone screen being small, would it be better to display the question and all answers in the same screen with the regular html zoom in and scroll mechanism?

vs. having two navigation arrows on (the right and left) to navigate and select answers.

Any other advice and enlightening observation is welcome.

Comment: Should i assume your talking about a smartphone which is NOT a touch-based phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a quiz which can have one correct answer,allowing the user to keep changing his answer kind of defeats the purpose since I can keep shifting between answers until I hit the right one. I would recommend allowing the user to select his answer and then freezing it so that he cannot make a change. You also should let the user know at once with regards to whether the answer he has chosen is correct or not instead of asking him to wait for another screen. This is because people would prefer instantaneous feedback and that would drive them to perform better. I prefer how quisr does this :

[image: This is when the questions are displayed]

*This is when the questions are displayed*

[image]

*This is when a correct answer is chosen*